# Server/Client app and JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string python

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous

I have async socket server file and client file.
When i send something like that "download filename.ex" to the client, this client's code hande my request:

```py
try:
    content = read(sp_data[-1]).decode('utf-8')
    print(content)
    msg = json.dumps({'file': sp_data[-1], 'command': data, 'content': content,
                                  'msg': f'[+] File {sp_data[-1]} has been successfully downloaded.'}).encode('utf-8')
except FileNotFoundError:
    msg = json.dumps({'msg': f'[-] File {sp_data[-1]} not found', 'command': data}).encode('utf-8')
    s.send(msg)
```

When client send some data to the socketserver, this server's code handle received message:

```py
def recv_message(client_socket):
    global messages
    data = json.loads(client_socket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8').strip()) ##Important here i got this error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 67 (char 66)
    raddr = get_raddr(str(client_socket))
    raddr = f'{raddr[0]}:{raddr[1]}'
    message = f'From: {raddr}\nCommand: {data["command"]}\nOutput: \n\n{data["msg"]}'
    try:
        d = messages[raddr]
        d.append(message)
        messages[raddr] = d
    except KeyError:
        messages[raddr] = [message]
    except AttributeError:
        print(message, messages)
    if 'content' in data.keys(): ##Important
        print(data['content'])
        threading.Thread(target=create_file, args=(data['file'], data['content'],), daemon=False).start()
```

Error:

```py
data = json.loads(client_socket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8').strip())
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 67 (char 66)
```

But server's code above give me this error when it receive message from the first code(when i send something like that "download file.ex" to the client, client detect my command as its special command, execute the first code, send json file to the server. But if i send "dir" command to the client, it will detect my command like shell command, will run command through subprocess, will send result to the server back and i won't get any errors.)

Note: I also reduced socketserver's code. Therefore, something in my code can work worse. The main goal of this post - make download feature works. I also understand that my code is big. I left "**##Important"** comments in my files. U can watch only code that located by these comments.

**Server**:

```py
import selectors
import socket
import threading
import json
import base64
import shlex

selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()

connections = {}


def accept_conn(server_socket):
    sock, addr = server_socket.accept()
    connections[len(connections) + 1] = [sock, f'{addr[0]}:{addr[-1]}']
    selector.register(fileobj=sock, events=selectors.EVENT_READ, data=recv_message)


s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('localhost', 4444))
s.listen()
selector.register(fileobj=s, events=selectors.EVENT_READ, data=accept_conn)

messages = {}

##Important 
def create_file(file, content): #content - base64 string
    print(content)
    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(base64.b64decode(content.encode('utf-8')))


def recv_message(client_socket):
    global messages
    data = json.loads(client_socket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8').strip()) ##Important here i got this error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 67 (char 66)
    raddr = get_raddr(str(client_socket))
    raddr = f'{raddr[0]}:{raddr[1]}'
    message = f'From: {raddr}\nCommand: {data["command"]}\nOutput: \n\n{data["msg"]}'
    try:
        d = messages[raddr]
        d.append(message)
        messages[raddr] = d
    except KeyError:
        messages[raddr] = [message]
    except AttributeError:
        print(message, messages)
    if 'content' in data.keys(): ##Important
        print(data['content'])
        threading.Thread(target=create_file, args=(data['file'], data['content'],), daemon=False).start()


def get_raddr(string):
    '''Get raddr parameter from client socket'''
    raddr = string.replace('>', '')
    return eval(raddr[raddr.find('raddr')::].replace('raddr=', ''))


def is_manage_string(sub, string):
    tokens = shlex.split(string)
    try:
        if len(tokens) == 2 and tokens[0] == sub and str(int(tokens[-1])):
            return True, int(tokens[-1])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return False


manage_process = False


def manage():
    global manage_process
    while True:
        manage_process = False
        command = input('>>> ').strip()
        if command == 'list':
            try:
                for i in range(1, len(connections) + 1):
                    print(f'{i}\t{connections[i][-1]}')
            except KeyError:
                pass
            if len(connections) == 0:
                print('[-] There are not any connections')
        elif 'manage' in command:
            index = is_manage_string('manage', command)
            if index:
                index = index[-1]
            else:
                print('[-] Invalid command\nUse manage "number_of_connection"\nEx: manage 1')
                continue
            if index >= 1 and index <= len(connections):
                sock, addr = connections[index]
                print(addr)
                print(f'{addr} is used')
                while True: ##Important here i launch loop which send data to socket
                    manage_process = True
                    command = input('>>> ').strip()
                    if command == 'messages':
                        try:
                            if messages[addr] == list():
                                print()
                                continue
                        except KeyError:
                            pass
                        try:
                            print('\n\n'.join(messages[addr]))
                        except KeyError:
                            print()
                    elif command == 'message':
                        try:
                            print(messages[addr][-1])
                        except:
                            print()
                    elif command == 'clear_messages':
                        try:
                            if messages[addr]:
                                messages[addr] = []
                        except KeyError:
                            print('[-] There are not any messages for cleaning up')
                    elif command == 'leave':
                        print(f'Leaving connection {addr}')
                        break
                    elif command: ##Important if command hasn't been detected as my special command(leave, messages), it will be executed like shell command
                        try:
                            sock.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
                            print(
                                'Your input has not been detected as special command and will execute like shell command or like client special command(ex: download; see client file)')
                        except ConnectionResetError:
                            print("Connection has been lost, therefore shell commands can't be used")
                    else:
                        continue

            else:
                print('[-] Invalid number of connection')

        elif command:
            print('[-] Invalid command\nType "help" to see avalible commands')

##Important
def event_loop():
    while True:
        data = selector.select()
        for key, _ in data:
            try:
                key.data(key.fileobj)
            except ConnectionResetError:
                selector.unregister(key.fileobj)


##Important
threading.Thread(target=manage, daemon=True).start()
event_loop()
```

**Client**:

```py
import socket
import subprocess
import shlex
import threading
import json
import base64


s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost', 4444))


##Important
def read(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        return base64.b64encode(f.read())


def runner(data):
    sp_data = shlex.split(data)
    try:
        print(sp_data)
        if len(sp_data) == 2 and sp_data[0] == 'download': ###Important here we create json object which will be send to socketserver
            try:
                content = read(sp_data[-1]).decode('utf-8')
                print(content)
                msg = json.dumps({'file': sp_data[-1], 'command': data, 'content': content,
                                  'msg': f'[+] File {sp_data[-1]} has been successfully downloaded.'}).encode('utf-8')
            except FileNotFoundError:
                msg = json.dumps({'msg': f'[-] File {sp_data[-1]} not found', 'command': data}).encode('utf-8')
            s.send(msg)
            return ''
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    command = subprocess.run(data, shell=True, encoding='cp866', text=True, capture_output=True)
    command = command.stderr if command.stderr else command.stdout
    command = json.dumps({'msg': command, 'command': data})
    s.send(command.encode('utf-8'))


while True:##Important
    data = s.recv(4096).decode('utf-8').strip()
    threading.Thread(target=runner, args=(data,)).start()
```

Comment: One way to debug this is to have a variable equal to ```client_socket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8').strip()``` and then print out the variable.

Comment: It looks like your expectation is that `send` will send everything you give as argument and `recv` will receive everything. Both expectations are wrong. You have to actually make sure that everything is send or use `sendall`. You also have to make sure that you got all data, by reading until you got the end of the JSON or by prefixing the message with a length and then reading this length or similar.

Comment: @SteffenUllruch, how can i do that? How to receive all data?
could u refactor my code?

Comment: @ewong, i added link

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, pls, tell me will it work. I Wanna download full directory.

Code:
https://pastebin.com/aCxF5b0A

Comment: @kali_xyyali: *"...  I Wanna download full directory. Code: ... "* - This is a different question than your original one. Please ask a new question instead with all necessary details contained in the question itself.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, i created new question. Pls, check it out

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64568418/transmit-folders-over-sockets-python

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, have u seen my new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import socket
import struct


class Socket(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        super().__init__(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def send_msg(self, msg):
        # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
        msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
        self.sock.sendall(msg)

    def recv_msg(self):
        # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
        raw_msglen = self.recv_all(4)
        if not raw_msglen:
            return None
        msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
        # Read the message data
        return self.recv_all(msglen)

    def recv_all(self, n):
        data = bytearray()
        while len(data) < n:
            packet = self.sock.recv(n - len(data))
            if not packet:
                return None
            data.extend(packet)
        return data
```

I reshaped ur code into Socket class.

Answer (score 1):

Solution - usage these features:

```py
def send_msg(sock, msg):
    # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)

def recv_msg(sock):
    # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    # Read the message data
    return recvall(sock, msglen)

def recvall(sock, n):
    # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
    data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data
```